# How to find and replace the text in .csproj using powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, csproj

How to find and replace the some text in csproj using powershell.
while we build csproj we need to update the studentpackage version in csproj . how find the value (version1) and update the same using powershell if we have version2.zip

```
<ItemGroup>
    <None Include="packages.config">
    </None>
    <Content Include="studentpackage\version1.zip">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="projectfile\sf.jpj" />
    <Content Include="projectfile\ee.xml" />
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  <ItemGroup>
```

Comment: It's an XML file, so edit it as an XML document.

Comment: FWIW, you'd want to query the document for something like `//Content[starts-with(@Include,"studentpackage") and contains(@Include,"version1")]`